# Give an Example to show that Theorem 3.4.9 fails if the hypothesis that X is a bounded sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Theorem 3.4.9 Let X=(xn) be a bounded sequence of real numbers and let x be an element of the real numbers have the property that every convergent subsequence of X converges to x. Then the sequence X converges to x.

I am assuming I am going to start this question off by assuming X is an unbounded sequence.

But what would an example look like?

Comment: $1,2,3,4,\dots$ and $x=17$, or $\pi$.  If you are in a less trivial mood, $1,1/2,3,1/4,4,1/5,\dots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, start with your favorite unbounded increasing sequence, then alternate the terms of that sequence with your favorite real constant $x$ to make a new sequence that will do the job. I leave it to you to justify.

Comment: so basically i take any unbounded sequence and find two subsequences that converge to two different limits?

Comment: Or any sequence that diverges to $\infty$ - it is vacuously true that every convergent subsequence has the same limit.

Comment: @Umberto: That's an excellent point. I think I was subconsciously considering $x$ as unique.

Comment: @Anonymous: Not quite. Rather, every convergent subsequence will (probably) be eventually constant (depending on what your favorite sequence is), and so converge to the same limit. However, the sequence itself doesn't converge, as it is unbounded.